# How to use regular expression to find keys in hash

Tags: regex, perl, hash

I have 6mio hashes and need to count how many of these have keys that start with `AA00`, `AB10` and how many of them have keys starting with with *both* strings.

For each hash I have done this:

```
if (exists $hash{AA00}) {
    $AA00 +=1;
}
if (exists $hash{AB10}) {
    $AB10 += 1;
}
if (exists $hash{AA00} and exists $hash{AA10}) {
    $both += 1;
}
```

but then I count only the number of hashes that contains exactly `AA00` or `AB10` as keys, but I would also like to count hashes that contain, say `AA001`. Can I use regular expression for this?

Comment: What is *"6mio"*? If you mean six million then that is normally written as *6M*

Comment: You ask for *keys that start with* and *keys that contain*, while your code finds *keys that equal*. My guess is that you mean the first, is that right?

Comment: I'm sorry that we haven't come up with anything you can use, but it would help if you engaged in a dialogue to resolve your problem. I have asked two questions in the comments here and you have answered neither. Once of the responses got to four upvotes without helping you at all. Please help us to help you.

Comment: Sorry 6M.And yes! I mean how many of my hashes contains at least one key that starts with AA00, and how many hashes contains at least one key that starts with AB10, and lastly how many hashes contains keys that starts with both AA00 and AB10.

Comment: Okay thank you. None of the answers you have been given so far solve your problem. You have to treat your array (?) of hashes as a simple array of lists of keys, and iterate through each of them. The speed advantage of hashes is nullified if you don't access them by a specific key, and if you are doing this a lot then you may want a better data structure in order to keep the run time to something reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

I completely misunderstood your question. To find the number of *hashes* with keys matching a regex (as opposed to the number of *keys* matching a regex in a *single* hash), you can still use the `grep` approach I outlined in my earlier answer. This time, however, you need to loop through your hashes (I assume you're storing them in an array if you have 6 million of them) and run `grep` twice on each one:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @array = (
    { AA00  => 'foo' },
    { AB10  => 'bar' },
    { AA001 => 'foo' },
    { AA00  => 'foo', AB10 => 'bar' }
);

my ($hashes_with_aa00, $hashes_with_ab10, $hashes_with_both) = (0, 0, 0);

foreach my $hash (@array) {
    my $aa_count = grep { /^AA00/ } keys %$hash;
    my $ab_count = grep { /^AB10/ } keys %$hash;

    $hashes_with_aa00++ if $aa_count;
    $hashes_with_ab10++ if $ab_count;
    $hashes_with_both++ if $aa_count and $ab_count;
}

say "AA00: $hashes_with_aa00";
say "AB10: $hashes_with_ab10";
say "Both: $hashes_with_both";
```

#### Output:

```
AA00: 3
AB10: 2
Both: 1
```

This works, but is pretty poor in terms of performance: `grep` loops through *every* element in the list of keys for each hash, and we're calling it *twice* per hash!

Since we don't care how many keys match in each hash, only whether there *is* a match, a better solution would be `any` from [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/List-MoreUtils-0.33/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm). `any` works much like `grep` but returns as soon as it finds a match. To use `any` instead of `grep`, change this:

```
foreach my $hash (@array) {
    my $aa_count = grep { /^AA00/ } keys %$hash;
    my $ab_count = grep { /^AB10/ } keys %$hash;

    $hashes_with_aa00++ if $aa_count;
    $hashes_with_ab10++ if $ab_count;
    $hashes_with_both++ if $aa_count and $ab_count;
}
```

to this:

```
use List::MoreUtils 'any';

foreach my $hash (@array) {
    my $aa_exists = any { /^AA00/ } keys %$hash;
    my $ab_exists = any { /^AB10/ } keys %$hash;

    $hashes_with_aa00++ if $aa_exists;
    $hashes_with_ab10++ if $ab_exists;
    $hashes_with_both++ if $aa_exists and $ab_exists;
}
```

Note that I changed the variable names to better reflect their meaning.

This is much better in terms of performance, but as Borodin notes in a comment on your question, you're losing the speed advantage of hashes by not accessing them with specific keys. You might want to change your data structure accordingly.

---

### Original Answer: Counting keys that match a regex in a *single* hash

*This is my original answer based on a misunderstanding of your question. I'm leaving it up because I think it could be useful for similar situations.*

To count the number of keys that match a regex in a single hash, you can use `grep`:

```
my $aa_count = grep { /^AA00/ } keys %hash;
my $ab_count = grep { /^AB10/ } keys %hash;
my $both     = $aa_count + $ab_count;
```

As HunterMcMillen points out in the comments, there's no need to search through the hash keys again to get the total count; in this case, you can simply add the two subtotals. You can get away with this because the two patterns you're searching for are mutually exclusive; in other words, you cannot have a key that both begins with `AA00` *and* `AB10`.

In the more general case, it might be possible for a single key to match both patterns (thanks Borodin). In that case, you cannot simply add up the two subtotals. For example, if you wanted your keys to merely contain `AA00` or `AB10` anywhere in the string, not necessarily at the beginning, you would need to do something like this:

```
my $aa_count = grep { /AA00/ } keys %hash;
my $ab_count = grep { /AB10/ } keys %hash;
my $both     = grep { /(?:AA00|AB10)/ } keys %hash;
```

Note that this calls `grep` multiple times, which means traversing the entire hash multiple times. This could be done more efficiently using a single `for` loop like FlyingFrog and Kenosis did.

Comment: couldn't `$both` just be `$aa_count + $ab_count`?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen That makes more sense.

Comment: Wouldn't the be more efficiently done in a single `for` loop, instead of traversing the hash twice?

Comment: You could do this using the smart match operator.

Comment: @hwnd As of 5.18, [smart match is experimental](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.18.0/pod/perldelta.pod#The_smartmatch_family_of_features_are_now_experimental): *"It is clear that smartmatch is almost certainly either going to change or go away in the future. Relying on its current behavior is not recommended."*

Comment: Thus I do agree with that.

Comment: @Kenosis: Unless there's a known performance problem, it's probably better to go with the code that is clearer, rather than the code that saves a few nanoseconds.

Comment: @hwnd: Sorry, you do agree with what?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: All that is certain is that `$both ≥ $aa_count` and  `$both ≥ $ab_count`. `$both` won't be the sum of the others unless neither is a substring of the other.

Comment: I'm sorry that I overlooked it before, but yet again this doesn't answer the OP's question, which is about how to count how many of a set of hashes contains a key starting with either or both given strings. This just looks at the keys of a single hash.

Comment: I guess i could use this, and if aa_count > 0, then I would add one to my $AA00 value, and if both are > 0 I could add 1 to my $both value?? But is this very effecient?

Comment: @user2335015 See my updated answer. Apologies that I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @Borodin Not sure why all four *(four!)* answerers misinterpreted the question, but after re-reading it multiple times and seeing the OP's comments, I think you're right, I was answering a different question altogether. Updated my answer once more.